# How to tell if Mother cat is lactating?

Tags: cats, feeding

How can I tell if my cat is producing milk for her newborn kittens?

My cat birthed 2 kittens on October 31st. One of them died yesterday morning. The other one has been crying a lot. I am concerned that the mother is not producing milk. How can I properly and accurately tell if she is producing milk or not?

I tried doing my research on the internet but did not find any truly conclusive answers. Mostly just heresay. I tried massaging and squeezing her nipples but nothing came out. Although I'm not convinced this means she's not producing milk as it might require suction to pull it out.

I also read to weigh the kitten twice a day and look for 5-10 grams of weight gain a day. I'm going to do this. But in the meantime I want to know if there is any direct way to know the mother is producing milk.

I started to go and buy milk replacement. But I would hate to ruin the natural feeding order and invest all that time into feeding the kitten if the mother is indeed making milk and I just cannot tell.